# How to call such a function? (pass argument)

Tags: web3js, truffle, javascript

For example, here is the code
What will the best code practice, either to repeat the code inside two different functions or what can I do?

```
OraclizeContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {

  console.log("Initializing");
  instance.deposit({from: fromAddress1, 
                    gas: 3000000,
                    value: web3.toWei(betAmount, 'ether')}) //betAmount is a input box and fetching its value into betamount variable and passing it over here
                               .then(function(v){
                                       console.log(v);
                                       console.log("Function Executed");

                                 });
                       }).then(function() {
                                              console.log("Testing");
                       }).catch(function(e) {
                                               console.log(e);
                       });
```

What I need is to create two separate buttons and call a very similar function 
except change the fromAddress1 to fromAddress2

I tried to enclose the whole code into two seperate button like this but it is not working?

```
document.getElementById("fromAddress1").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
```

### Any solution?

I understand that i need to take arguments and pass it 
But i need to call it on click of 2 different buttons
like 
document.getElementById("fromAddress1").addEventListener("submit", function(e){

On click of this button, but how will pass the argument and invoke this OraclizeContract.deployed()?

Asking this because this seems to be a different function I have sent arguments to normal functions like

play (uint x, uint y)

but have never sent arguments to like this.

OraclizeContract.deployed().then(function(instance)

So i am confused

Comment: Implement a function which takes the address as input, and call it with a different input for each button (BTW, this is a general Javascript question, and it is not specifically related to Ethereum in any manner).

Comment: how to pass arguments to such a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do something like:

```
OraclizeContract.deployed().then(function(instance, fromAddressX) {

  console.log("Initializing");
  instance.deposit({from: fromAddressX, 
                    gas: 3000000,
    ....
```

This way you would pass the `fromAddress` you want as an input argument to your function.

```
document.getElementById("fromAddress1").addEventListener("submit", function(e, <fromAddress1 value>){
```

Like-wise... Hope it helps.

Comment: I updated my question on how to make the function accept arguments?

Comment: How to pass arguments to this ?

Comment: first I suggest you read about promise/resolve functions (.then()...). You will see that they work in a similar way as normal functions, but they occur in a certain order .. Basically, you say: "when OraclizeContract.deployed() finishes ... then execute function(instance, artgument)... 

Like-wise, you should Button1 -> `document.getElementById("fromAddress1").addEventListener("submit", function(e, <PUT HERE THE VALUE OF fromAddress1>)`..

Button 2-> `document.getElementById("fromAddress2").addEventListener("submit", function(e, <PUT HERE THE VALUE OF fromAddress2>)`

Comment: But, as @goodvibration said, this is a js question rather than Ethereum. So I suggest moving this to the js StackOverflow. There are people with more expertise than me that can help you